# C++ with OpenCv OR C# with aforge.net

Tags: computer-vision

Now I have project about sign language recognition , so to accomplish this project I need to program image processing,detection,tracking,recognition phases....etc

I would like to know what is the best to use:

VC++ with OpenCv

or

VC# with aforge.net ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, that is something only you know. Things to consider:

Operational: what do you know? do you know c++ and c# equally well? what do you feel most comfortable in? Are you primarily based on windows? Will your application to run mainly on windows?

Engineering: does it have to work in real time? how important is it that it works in real time? how many man hours do you have for this project?

Scientific: what methods do you plan to use? are you sure these methods will work or is there some trial and error required?

As you can see, there is no "best" in this type of things everything is a tradeoff, a balance between many competing needs.